# Matching user profiles with employment opportunities

Tags: machine-learning, text-analysis

I am currently working on a software which can connect users to jobs based on their user profiles. I ran text analytics on the job descriptions and derived important keywords from it. I have also collected user information from their profile. Matching the jobs to the user profiles seems to be a challenging task. Are there any Machine Learning based algorithms which can be used for match making?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so basically, you have keywords for each job description and then you have some sort of text data (user profiles) to which you try to match those keywords.

Since your training data (user profiles) is not labeled, the [supervised learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supervised_learning) will not help you here. [Unsupervised learning](https://www.mathworks.com/discovery/unsupervised-learning.html) (clustering) could maybe help you in finding a certain patterns (keywords) from a loads of user profiles, but you would certainly need to experiment with different sorts of techniques (such as [gaussian mixture models](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/mixture.html) etc.) and observe possible patterns.

A simpler thing you could maybe do is to derive/find keywords also for each user profile(in other words to identify how many of your job keywords also exist in user profile) and then compare a distance between them using [cosine similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosine_similarity). You would then only need to determine the minimal angle threshold. This would be a parameter to play with. Of course you would need to vectorize your text data using bigrams or similar; if you use python there already is [feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) in scikit). You could possibly also use [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf) vectorizer on both, the job description and user profile but with some heavy and well determined words stop list.

Comment: Hi, the post is 3 years old. Is there some evolution in this area? Some examples?